# Не найден класс Main при запуске из командной строки

Tags: java

Написал код:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner str = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(str.nextLine());

    }

}
```

И далее вписал в консоли: `javac Main.java` и `java Main` (чтобы запустить программу)

После этого, мне в консоли выдается такая ошибка:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/company/Main (wrong name: Main)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В вашем классе указан пакет `package com.company`. По соглашению, класс должен лежать в директории `com/company/Main.java`.

Компилируем:

```sh
javac com/company/Main.java
```

Запускаем:

```sh
java com.company.Main
```

Если по какой-то причине вы не хотите структурировать классы по соответствующим директориям, то `javac` может создать структуру за вас, для этого можно воспользоваться опцией `-d` и указать `.` — текущую директорию:

```java
javac -d . Main.java
```

Запускаем по-прежнему:

```java
java com.company.Main
```

Comment: Да, действительно помогло!
Спасибо за помощь.